# Change an App Setting when updating the iPhone application to a new Version

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to change the URL that my application connects to, to a new sever. The problem is, the URL value is saved in a settings file. When I *update* the application to the new version, the *old* file is read from the device, and overwrites my settings. What I want is to use the *new* URL the *first time* the updated version is launched. After that, I am happy to read the URL from the file.
Is there any way I can determine this is *the first time after an update* when I lauch the application?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for shouting! I was just trying to make the important part of the question easy to read. My bad!

Comment: Use italics next time. Surround words with *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520079/change-an-app-setting-when-updating-the-iphone-application-to-a-new-version/6520130#6520130), you can get the current version by reading the `CFBundleVersion` of your app's bundle. The problem with this approach is that a user might not install "version 1" of your app. Instead, I suggest putting something like the following in your app's `didFinishLaunching` method:

```
#define kSettings [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if(![kSettings objectforKey:@"isFirstRun"]){

  // You could check the version here 
  // and do some initial setting up.

  [kSettings setBool:NO forKey:@"isFirstRun"];

}
```

Then, for each subsequent version, you can *add* another if block with another flag to check for that version, like so:

```
if(![kSettings objectForKey:@"isFirstRunForVersionX"]){

  //  Do some version specific set up here.

  [kSettings setBool:NO forKey:@"isFirstRunForVersionX"];
}
```

I've successfully used this approach in several of my apps.

Comment: Not necessary I think. If the app is being installed the first time, then there won't be a key for the current version. In that case, app can detect that it has been installed. Every other time the version changes, its an update.

Answer (score 1):

To determine it it's the first launch after the update, you could retrieve the version number with this piece of code:

```
NSString* v = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

And compare it to a previous value you have saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can store flag in NSUSerDefault. So You need to check first time if isFirstTime==0 then do your code and make isFirstTime=1; So it only runs first time.

Comment: I guess he just want to check this whether user's install app or update app ?

Comment: No he wants to use a different URL every time the app is updated. So as soon as the app is updated, he must know. `isFirstTime` will tell him only the first time the app is installed. He won't know if it is updated or not.

Comment: Ok Thanks sorry I misunderstood.